# Transfering values from a table row to another page using click() in Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, click, row

The script lets me show the current row text and displays the whole record as a line of text. But I need to access each TD of table to fetch all the data separately from the same row.

Actually, I have a table of persons. So, If I click on a single record then I want to show the details of that person/record on another page. Like a more detailed view of the particular record.

[Script]

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tbody tr').click(function(){
        var a=$(this).text();
        document.write(a);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: how about? 
$('table tbody tr td').click(function(){....})

Comment: @SergiuCostas  well that would just take the value of the TD which I click on... not the full row

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? it should be only TD value

Comment: I kind of want to take the whole row and split it up to get the information because right now all the TD's are merged into a single text line due to .text() function

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/79mv7a4w/ -> Click on Buttons 111 or 112

Comment: @SergiuCostas Yes! I did try. It only takes the value of clicked TD. I need the full row

Comment: The answer of @ankitchaudhary seems to be the needed one. By clicking on TD, you will obtain back the javascript array back with all TDs values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse all the `tds` in the listener for the clicked row using `.each()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tbody tr').click(function(){
        var a=[];
        $(this).find('td').each(function(){
        a.push($(this).text());
        });
     console.log(a);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td>B</td>
<td>C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>D</td>
<td>E</td>
<td>F</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This seems to be working but the output is in log. I need each TD in a separate var (variable)

Comment: Log is just to show what is present in `a`. All value of TD is stored in variable `a` as an array

Comment: Also I've sophisticated TR, which includes Checkboxes and images and buttons. I dont want them to select, I want just the text.

Comment: Those will be ignored by `text()`. It will be better if you can showcase your html

Comment: I just did an alert(a[3])  and in alert it says "undefined".

Comment: That is quite obvious. Counting in array starts from 0 So there is no element at index 3

Comment: It looks good It will return empty string for TD containing IMG and check box.

Comment: I just check your code here (https://jsfiddle.net/pn1w8zw1/) and it works.. But not in my project. Looks like there's something in my project. Let me check

Comment: Problem Solved.. Thanks